# Knockout custom binding for indeterminate checkbox won't work

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js, custom-binding

Let's put it short: This is my knockout custom binding for putting a checkbox in indeterminate state.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nullableChecked = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value == null) element.indeterminate = true;
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, function () { return value; });
    }
};
```

If the initial value is `null` everything works fine and checkbox is put in indeterminate state but when I click the checkbox it doesn't seem to update the bound property's value to false/true accordingly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Any chance of putting a jsFiddle together to give us something to play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling Init.

Simply proxy the init function for checked in your nullableChecked init function like you did in the update.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nullableChecked = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
          ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value == null) element.indeterminate = true;
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

Without the init, it's never actually setting up a "click" binding on the checkbox to tell knockout that something has changed. If you look at the debug code (http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js), you'll see that init uses jQuery to set up a 'click' event on the checkbox to update the observable when the value changes.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['checked'] = {
'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var updateHandler = function() {
        var valueToWrite;
        if (element.type == "checkbox") {
            valueToWrite = element.checked;
        } else if ((element.type == "radio") && (element.checked)) {
            valueToWrite = element.value;
        } else {
            return; // "checked" binding only responds to checkboxes and selected radio buttons
        }

        var modelValue = valueAccessor(), unwrappedValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(modelValue);
        if ((element.type == "checkbox") && (unwrappedValue instanceof Array)) {
            // For checkboxes bound to an array, we add/remove the checkbox value to that array
            // This works for both observable and non-observable arrays
            var existingEntryIndex = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(unwrappedValue, element.value);
            if (element.checked && (existingEntryIndex < 0))
                modelValue.push(element.value);
            else if ((!element.checked) && (existingEntryIndex >= 0))
                modelValue.splice(existingEntryIndex, 1);
        } else {
            ko.expressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty(modelValue, allBindingsAccessor, 'checked', valueToWrite, true);
        }
    };
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", updateHandler);

    // IE 6 won't allow radio buttons to be selected unless they have a name
    if ((element.type == "radio") && !element.name)
        ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName']['init'](element, function() { return true });
},
```

**Edit:** Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cclose/NFfVn/

Comment: Actually, to enable updates from code, the update callback in the handler should set the indeterminate property to false if the value != null

Comment: This seems to work with Knockout <= 2.3.0, but does not work with Knockout >= 3.0.0.  Any ideas why?  Is there a solution that works with Knockout 3.0.0?

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is here looking to have a select all type checkbox show as intermediate if not all of its sub items are checked, you can use a simple binding like this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.indeterminateValue = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        element.indeterminate = value;
    }
};
```

then you can use it like this

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedAllProduce, indeterminateValue: selectedProduce().length > 0 && selectedProduce().length < produce.length" title="Select all/none"/>
```

Here is a fiddle showing it working on the computed observable select all example
https://jsfiddle.net/deannorth/crqwac12/

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Fodagus works with Knockout <= 2.3.0, but in Knockout >= 3.0.0, `ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update` is undefined.

We found that this works for us in Knockout 3.1.0:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.nullableChecked = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (value == null) {
                element.indeterminate = true;
            }
            else {
                element.indeterminate = false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Are we missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

In the new versions of `knockout 3.0.0` and above. The update method in the `checkbox` binding handler is removed. Therefore you should create a `click event` in the `init` function to trigger the update method whenever the `checkbox` is clicked. Below is an example of a binding handler to transform a `jquery checkbox` into a `uniform checkbox`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedUniform =
{
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor);
        $(element).uniform().on('click', ko.bindingHandlers.checkedUniform.update);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) 
    {
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, valueAccessor);
        $.uniform.update($(element));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `checked` handler receives an accessor to the value that was stored, not the observable that was holding the value. So the observable never gets any value changes caused by the handler.  I think you should be able to just pass in the value accessor as is.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nullableChecked = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value == null) element.indeterminate = true;
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```